# Proving statements about class terms in ${\sf ZF}$

Tags: set-theory

I recently learned the notion of a class term in axiomatic set theory and have a question regarding this concept. A class term $X$ is given by the string of symbols
$$\{x\mid\phi(x)\},$$ where $\phi(x)$ is a first order formula in the language set theory. Class terms main purpose is to improve readability of formulas. If $z$ is a variable and $Y$ is another class term then:

- $z \in X$ stands for $\phi(z)$
- $z = X$ stands for $\forall u (u \in z \leftrightarrow \phi(u))$
- $X \in Y$ stands for $\exists v (v = X \land v \in Y)$

We let $\emptyset$ denote the class defined $\neg x = x$ and let $V$ be the class defined by $x=x$. Finally we call a class term $X$ a set, if ${\sf ZF}\vdash X \in V$. For more information see [these](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/ag/logik/teaching/2019WS/logik/Current_Scriptum.pdf) lecture notes by Peter Koepke starting in Section 19.3.

If $\xi$ is a variable or a class term we define the class term $\bigcup \xi$ as $\{ y \mid \exists z (z \in \xi \land y \in z) \}$. With this notation we can state the union axiom of ${\sf ZF }$ as $$ \forall x \, \bigcup x \in V.$$

Intuitively the above axiom says ''Whenever we have a set, the union over its elements is still a set''. So one could hope that for any class term $X$ it is also true, that $${\sf ZF } \vdash X \in V \to \bigcup X \in V.$$
But is it? I tried coming up with a proof but as I my background in set theory is very little I couldn't get a grip on it.

Comment: IF $X \in V$ then - as you says above - $X$ is a set. Thus, Union Axiom applies.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I tried coming up with a derivation, things got a bit messy and I didn't know how to proceed. But I guess that's the nature of formal proofs.

Comment: Apply your third bullet above (on top of the post): $X \in V$  stands for $∃v(v=X ∧ v ∈ V)$. Thus, we have a set - call it $x$ - such that $x=X$.

Comment: Thus, the formal proof will be: ${\sf ZF }, X \in V \vdash x=X$ by def of class term. Then $\vdash \bigcup x \in V$ by Union, then $\bigcup X \in V$ by identity. Conclusion: ${\sf ZF }, X \in V \vdash \bigcup X \in V$, from which the conclusion follows by Deduction Th.

Comment: Ok, I get that ${\sf ZF} \vdash x = X \to \bigcup X \in V$, but we only have ${\sf ZF}, X \in V \vdash \exists x\, x = X$ right? Because ${\sf ZF}, X \in V \vdash  x = X$ would imply ${\sf ZF}, X \in V \vdash \forall x\, x = X$ which is not true.

Comment: Ah I see: ${\sf ZF}, X \in V \vdash \exists x\, x = X$ and ${\sf ZF}, X \in V \vdash  x = X \to \bigcup X \in V$ implies ${\sf ZF}, X \in V \vdash  \bigcup X \in V$. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Not clear... the axioms says $\forall x (\bigcup x \in V)$; thus, having proved that $\exists x (x=X)$, we use it with Universal Instantiation and have $(\bigcup X \in V)$. There is nowhere $\forall x (x=X)$.

Comment: No, I meant that in your above comment you said that ${\sf ZF}, X\in V \vdash x = X$, which I believe was a typo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146667/discussion-between-vava123-and-mauro-allegranza).